# How do I align text to the left and an image to the right in a UIButton programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to create a button that has 16 padding on the left and rights sides of a button.

My `UIButton`override

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    backgroundColor =  UIColor.white
    setTitleColor(UIColor.primary, for: .normal)
    setTitleColor(UIColor.primary, for: .highlighted)
    titleLabel!.font = UIFont.mediumHeadline


    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.bounds.width - 32, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

and in my controller:

```
func setupHeadingButton() {
        headerButton.setImage(UIImage.rightNavigationArrow, for: .normal)

    }
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I set the image:

```
headerButton.setImage(UIImage.settingsUpArrow, for: .normal)
```

then swap the image and button and change their insets that incorporates the 16 padding on both sides:

```
headerButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -(headerButton.imageView?.frame.size.width)! + 16, 0, (headerButton.imageView?.frame.size.width)!)
        let leftPadding =  headerButton.bounds.width - (headerButton.imageView?.bounds.width)!-16
        headerButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftPadding, 0, -(headerButton.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change values for titleEdgeInsets and imageEdgeInsets button's properties.

and also for implement this you can create custom UIView with override method: func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set,  with event: UIEvent?)

Comment: Ok I did override it. what should should I set the vales to?

Comment: no, it's two different implementation of this task.
or you change values of property, or create custom UIView instead UIButton

Comment: what should I set the values for `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEsgeInsets`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by **UIEdgeInsets**

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.view.bounds.width - 32, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

change the left property based on your desire.
the result of the above code is like this:

[image]

don't forget to change the alignment of the button to the left:

[image]

Comment: I tried that, it does not work. I have updated my question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

First option is to configure button with autolayout (Im using Snapkit framework beacuse of best readability) and the second option is to configure it with frame.

```
import UIKit

final class CustomButton: UIButton {

    let leftImageView: UIImageView
    let centerLabel: UILabel

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        centerLabel = UILabel()
        leftImageView = UIImageView()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        centerLabel = UILabel()
        leftImageView = UIImageView()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    fileprivate func configureWithSnapKit() {


        setTitle("", for: .normal)

        // Spacing view for space between imageview and label
        let spacingView1 = UIView()
        let spacingView2 = UIView()
        let spacingView3 = UIView()

        // Configuring stack view

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [spacingView1, centerLabel, spacingView2, leftImageView, spacingView3])
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill

        leftImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        leftImageView.contentMode = .center

        centerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        centerLabel.font = Fonts.sfui_medium(size: 12)
        centerLabel.textColor = Colors.white
        centerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        // Adding subviews
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        // SnapKit autolayout
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(0)
        }

        spacingView1.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(16)
        }

        spacingView3.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(16)
        }

        leftImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(22)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func configureWithFrame() {

        setTitle("", for: .normal)

        // Spacing view for space between imageview and label
        let spacingView = UIView()

        // Configuring stack view

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [centerLabel, spacingView, leftImageView])
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill

        leftImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        leftImageView.contentMode = .center

        centerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        centerLabel.font = Fonts.sfui_medium(size: 12)
        centerLabel.textColor = Colors.white
        centerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        // Adding subviews
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 0, width: self.frame.width - 32, height: self.frame.height)
    }
}
```